# Listing Unmatched Positions out of One Table where reference date is specific

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pretty new to SQL, but i need to use it for my new job as the project requires it and as I am a non-IT-guy, it is more difficult for me, because thats my first time I work professionally with SQL.

Hopefully you can help me with it: (Sry for my english, i am a non-native speaker)

I need to start a query where I get unequal IDs from 2 different reference dates.

So I have one Table with following data:

```
DATES     ID        AMOUNT   SID
201910    122424    99999    1
201911    41241242  99999    2
201912    12412424  -22222   3
...
```

GOAL:

So the ID's from the DATE: 201911 shall be compared with those from 201910
and the query should show me the unequal ID's. So only the unmatched ID's shall be displayed.

Out of this query, the Amount should be summed up and grouped into SIDs.

Comment: Can you please provide sample table data _and the expected result_ in properly formatted columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two dates and you want `sid`s that are only on one of them, then:

```
select sid
from t
where date in (201911, 201910)
group by sid
having count(distinct date) = 1;
```

Comment: well at first, i want to a table, which shows me the all ID's of 201911 and 201910 which are not in each others reference date.

Comment: @EnzoNguyen . . . This displays the unmatched ids for the two months, as your question requests.